# Angular 2. Не появялется template

Tags: angular2

Решил создать проект на Angular 2. Есть компонент, упакованный в отдельную папку[image: вот тут структура проекта].

Ну возьмем для примера компонент task-form.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task-form',
  templateUrl: './task-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-form.component.css']
})
export class TaskFormComponent implements OnInit {

    title:string;
    description:string;
    price:number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Теперь файл app.component.html:

```
<form class="forms">
    <h3 class="forms-header">Add new task</h3>
   <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="label-wrapper">
        <label for="title">Название</label>
        <label for="description">Описание</label>
        <label for="price">Цена</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input name="title" #newtitle/>
        <input name="description" #newdescription/>
        <input name="price" #newprice/>
    </div>

   </div>
  </form>
  <button (click)="addNewTask(newtitle, newdescription, newprice)"
          class="bottons">Add</button>
```

И проблема вот в чем. Если этот код поместить в task-form.component.html, либо в template у tasc-form.component.ts и добавим наш компонент в index.html, ничего не отображается. Почему? Может я зависимости где-то не дописал, либо еще что-то, но ума дать пока не могу. Вот еще app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TaskFormComponent } from './task-form/task-form.component';
import { TaskListComponent } from './task-list/task-list.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TaskFormComponent,
    TaskListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Насчет зависимостей. Компоненты добавлялись не вручную, а через `ng generate component`

Comment: в task-form.component.ts нет функции addNewTask(), но удаление кнопки проблему не решает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для загрузки компонента `task-form.component` добавьте в файл `app.component.html` следующую строку:

```
<app-task-form> </app-task-form>
```

Comment: А ларчик просто открывался